# Best way to define eloquent relationship with comma separated value

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am confused how should I define or design database to get best eloquent result.
Sometimes I need to save comma separated value in column for simplicity.
Suppose I have sub_modules and routes table 
where one sub_modules may have many routes. 
I am making sub_modules with some routes.
One sub_modules may have more than 1000 routes.
That's why I want to put those routes list with comma separated in sub_modules table.
Current structure::
sub modules table:
id---name----route_ids
routes table:
id---url---name

should I define one to many relations or current structure is better?
If I keep current structure then how can define eloquent relationship in SubModule model class?
I have some other table that will be big if I use one to many relationship using third table.
Please suggest me some better solutions.

Comment: There is no native support for this in Laravel. I created a package that allows you to define many-to-many relationships with JSON arrays: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

Comment: Can i use like: 2,3,5,9,8 in column ? Field data type is varchar. Is your package support this structure? @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: It has to be valid JSON, so `[2,3,5,9,8]`.

Comment: column data type? @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: select version() =>10.1.35 MariaDB @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: The package doesn't support MariaDB (limitation of Laravel).

Comment: In your doc you said in Compatibility section that: MariaDB 10.2+ @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: Yes, and Laravel 5.8 which will be released in 2019.

Comment: Oh! That means your package will support mariadb if i upgrade laravel 5.8 , right? @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: Yes, Laravel 5.8 and MariaDB 10.2.